# Change loaded content in an HTML file with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Some content, in this case a navbar (navbar.php), is loaded into the index.html by Javascript. Now I want to change a navbar list item from "Home" to "Something else" using Javascript. But it seems that the script can not see the loaded content. The console gives an „*document.getElementById(...) is null*“ error. Following the code:

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
  <head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(function() {
        $("#navbar").load("navbar.php");
        return false;
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <header>
          <div id="navbar">

          </div>                        
        </header>
        <main>
        
        </main>
        <footer>
        
        </footer>
        <script>
          let myChange = document.getElementById("change").innerHTML;                   
          myChange = "<a href='somethingelse.html'>Something else</a>";
        </script>
      </body>
    </div>
  </div>
</html>
```

navbar.php

```
<div>
  <ul>
    <li id="change"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li ><a href="logout.php">Logout</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Any idea what is wrong in the code?
Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: innerHTML is not a reference to it. You are storing the string into the variable. `let myChange = document.getElementById("change");myChange.innerHTML='foo';`

Comment: You are reading the element before it exists. You would have the code run after the load runs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to use the [load's callback function](https://api.jquery.com/load/#callback-function) for load to know when the content has been added to the document.

```js
$("#navbar").load("navbar.php", function() {
  const myChange = document.getElementById("change");
  myChange.innerHTML = "<a href='somethingelse.html'>Something else</a>";
});
```

Comment: many thanks, that was the trick.... thumbs up